How to simulate ADS131 ADC ic, its simulator model is not available anywhere. Is there any software(proteus/altium/kicad) on which i can simulate it?
I want to simulate this ADS131 IC as a part of bigger circuit but I'm not able to find this IC's simulator model in the proteus than how to do simulation?

ask the manufacturer

The ADS131 is an ADC; these are typically not very well-supported for simulation. There is an IBIS model, but that's all; you're not  likely to get a full SPICE model even if you ask for one. Still, can't hurt to ask.

Than how to simulate such circuits containing this ICs, should I directly go for hardware and play around it?
